# Can't find the New label tools in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, labeling

I can't find the New label tools in QGIS developed by sourcepole. I'm using QGIS 1.7.4. Is it a QGIS tool or a plugin?

Comment: Which new label tool?

Comment: Do you mean these? http://www.sourcepole.ch/new-label-tools-in-qgis

Answer (score 3):

According to their website http://www.sourcepole.ch/new-label-tools-in-qgis:

> three new editing tools to manipulate text labels are now in the QGIS developer version

So no chance for Qgis 1.7.4

Comment: They should be in 1.8 though.

Comment: Yes, so not very "new". But looks completely different in "gis" icon style...

Comment: That's my preferred icon style, too. They are just much clearer to interpret. Also, upgrading to 1.8 is totally worth it, there have been quite some interesting new features besides the labeling tools.